# Declare a delete statement in NotORM

Tags: php, notorm

How to declare a Delete statement in NotORM like this code:
`mysql_query("DELETE FROM pspaym WHERE F4='$d' ");`

Comment: How did you write you select ??? Have you gone through tutorial ?

Comment: $db->select() like that sir

Answer (score 3):

```
$notORM->pspaym("F4", $d)->delete();
```